# Ascending sort date

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sorting

i want sort date, and use this code:

```
SELECT     TID, TName, TOrder
FROM         tblOrder
ORDER BY TOrder
```

Result:

> 1 maikel  null
>
> 5 emil null
>
> 4 kabol 1
>
> 3 samin 2
>
> 2 mihad 3

but i want this result:

> 4 kabol 1
>
> 3 samin 2
>
> 2 mihad 3
>
> 1 maikel  null
>
> 5 emil null

please help me for Ascending sort.

Comment: Which database are you working with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  TID, TName, TOrder
FROM    tblOrder
ORDER   BY  CASE WHEN TORDER IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            TOrder
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e921c/2)

Linq:

```
var x = from a in tblOrder
        orderby (a.TORDER == null ? 1 : 0), a.TORDER 
        select a
```

Comment: woooooooow :-) its ok :-) please convert this code to LINQ.thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "ORDER BY TOrder ASC".

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2007/10/19/3048.aspx):

```
SELECT     TID, TName, TOrder
FROM         tblOrder
ORDER BY COALESCE(TOrder,'9999-12-31 23:59:59.997')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest way for SQL Server:

```
SELECT TID, TName, TOrder
FROM   tblOrder
ORDER BY isnumeric(TOrder) DESC, TOrder
```

For other databases like MySQL and PostgreSQL, there is simpler solution:

```
SELECT TID, TName, TOrder
FROM   tblOrder
ORDER BY TOrder IS NULL, TOrder
```

For Oracle and PostgreSQL, this works and will take advantage of possible index on TOrder:

```
SELECT TID, TName, TOrder
FROM   tblOrder
ORDER BY TOrder ASC NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this query and [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf98b/1)

```
SELECT TID, TName, TOrder INTO #TempTab
FROM         tblOrder
WHERE TOrder IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TOrder
SELECT * FROM #TempTab 
UNION ALL
SELECT     TID, TName, TOrder
FROM         tblOrder
WHERE TOrder IS NULL;
```